# opencv kmeans clustering multiple Mats

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

This question is specific to opencv(c++). I was looking to cluster multiple Matricies/images together to create a single row of cluster centres and get the measure of the fit.

I'm currently using the [BOWTrainer](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html#bowkmeanstrainer) class, using the .add method to add mats then using the .cluster method to generate the centres. It doesn't however output a metric to describe the closeness of the fit though. I know the vanilla [kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#double%20kmeans(InputArray%20data,%20int%20K,%20InputOutputArray%20bestLabels,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20attempts,%20int%20flags,%20OutputArray%20centers)) function returns a compactness metric but i haven't been able to find a way to cluster multiple distinct mat's with this, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [bagofwords.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/bagofwords.cpp), `kmeans` compactness measure is not stored into `BOWTrainer`.

```
Mat BOWKMeansTrainer::cluster( const Mat& _descriptors ) const
{
    Mat labels, vocabulary;
    kmeans( _descriptors, clusterCount, labels, termcrit, attempts, flags, vocabulary );
    return vocabulary;
}
```

so you can't retrieve that value directly from `BOWKMeansTrainer`.

---

You can, however, perform the same operations as in `BOWKMeansTrainer::cluster()` and retrieve the compactness measure:

```
// int clusterCount = ...
// TermCriteria termcrit = ...
// int attempts = ...
// int flags = ...

// Create trainer
BOWKMeansTrainer bow(clusterCount, termcrit, attempts, flags);

// Add some descriptors
// bow.add(...);

// Retrieve descriptors
vector<Mat> descriptors = bow.getDescriptors();

// Check that !descriptors.empty()

// Form a single descriptor matrix (as in "Mat BOWKMeansTrainer::cluster() const")

int descCount = 0;
for( size_t i = 0; i < descriptors.size(); i++ )
    descCount += descriptors[i].rows;

Mat mergedDescriptors( descCount, descriptors[0].cols, descriptors[0].type() );
for( size_t i = 0, start = 0; i < descriptors.size(); i++ )
{
    Mat submut = mergedDescriptors.rowRange((int)start, (int)(start + descriptors[i].rows));
    descriptors[i].copyTo(submut);
    start += descriptors[i].rows;
}

// Perform cluster (as in "Mat BOWKMeansTrainer::cluster( const Mat& _descriptors ) const")

Mat labels, vocabulary;
double compactness = kmeans( mergedDescriptors, clusterCount, labels, termcrit, attempts, flags, vocabulary );
```